# how to make a group of lines use just one key in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have three group of lines, each group has three lines. I want the lines in the same group use the same style line, and just want the key to differentiate different group, no need to differentiate different lines in the same group.

I use the below methods, certainly it doesn't work. How should I do?

```
plot \
    "a1.txt" title "a" ls 1, \
    "a2.txt" title "a" ls 1, \
    "a3.txt" title "a" ls 1, \
    "b1.txt" title "b" ls 2, \
    "b2.txt" title "b" ls 2, \
    "b3.txt" title "b" ls 2, \
    "c1.txt" title "c" ls 3, \
    "c2.txt" title "c" ls 3, \
    "c3.txt" title "c" ls 3
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, it might sufficient to specify the title just for the first line of a particular group (and enforce an empty title for the other members of the same group):

```
plot \
    "a1.txt" title "a" ls 1, \
    "a2.txt" title "" ls 1, \
    "a3.txt" title "" ls 1, \
    "b1.txt" title "b" ls 2, \
    "b2.txt" title "" ls 2, \
    "b3.txt" title "" ls 2, \
    "c1.txt" title "c" ls 3, \
    "c2.txt" title "" ls 3, \
    "c3.txt" title "" ls 3
```